# Svg image become blurry after zoom using react-native-svg-pan-zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, svgpanzoom

I'm using the `react-native-svg-pan-zoom` library for panning and zooming the svg component in react native. But the problem is that when I'm setting `maxScale` more than 1 the components become blurred. Please help me to resolve this issue... When I increase the scale value then the quality is increased but the svg goes outside the canvas so its looks cropped.

Current output: svg becomes blurry after zoom as well as tree size (svg size) increases.

Expected output: I don't want the image to blur while zooming.

Comment: Does your .svg include bitmap content?

Comment: its use some ,png but the other svg elements are also blur.